# Enabling Hangouts chat APIs fails without meaningful errors

Tags: google-console-developer, google-api-console, google-hangouts

Currently working on running the sample bot app detailed: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot

I am stuck on step 3 d..."In the Google Cloud Console, enable the Hangouts Chat API by doing the following"

When I attempt to configure the project's hangout chats API application info page I am presented with an error:
[error message from cloud console, no error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUe4r.png)

- I have tried entering the details many times and am sure everything is accurate.
- I cant seem to get past this screen, nor can I understand what I am missing/doing wrong
- I have the role of owner for this project

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have a gsuite account for this. The error is related to for whom the bot should be enabled. Now there are two options

1. Everyone in your domain (This works only if the gsuite admin has enabled the bot for the domain and your deployment Id is not pointing to HEAD version)
2. For specific people (Here you can specify people who can install the bot and use it.)

You should use 2nd option for testing purpose. Once you're done testing it, update the settings in gsuite admin console for bot and then deploy your app script code with a production version and then enable Everyone in your domain option again so that others can start using it.